# how to add text in svg object inside javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg

How can I add a text node inside javascript svg object . I am using this object , but I don't know how to add text into svg .

```
 var circlemarker = {        
        path: 'M-5,0a5,5 0 1,0 10,0a5,5 0 1,0 -10,0 z',
        fillColor:'yellow', //'#f39c13',
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        scale: 3,
        strokeColor: '#f7692c',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        data: 'My text' // this is not working
    };
```

Comment: Did you actually searched this in google? [First link](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) So it seems that you must have __object__ `text` inside your `circlemarker `

Comment: Yes I am searched  many hours , but all examples are in html style , but I want this in javascript , so that I can use it in google-map marker .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, read more about SVG [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/)

TL;DR 
SVG is just set of elements that represent a geometric figure.
Simple SVG looks like

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   <text x="30" y="40">aaa</text>
</svg>
```

Notice that `<text></text>` is an element, so it cannot be used inside `<circle></circle>` but underneath

So to add text, create new text element like this

```
var textmarker = {
    x: 10,
    y: 40,
    fontSize: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Verdana',
    value: 'some text' //this might be tricky, as per docs, text element filled by innerHTML property, try data, text, innerHTML, etc
}
```